# NSURLConnection errors

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I have a problem with my iPhone application, i am trying to connect to my PHP script to get information about something.

I have this code that takes the respone from PHP Link(total tables) and puts it into responseRandomID.

But when i try and use it in a Random function, it comes up with an error when i try and run it?

connectionDidReciveData:

```
if(connection == connectionRandomID) {
        NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        responseRandomID = [temp intValue];
    }
```

connectionDidFinishLoading:

```
if(connection == connectionRandomID) {
        randomid = (int)1 + arc4random() % (1-responseRandomID+1);
    }
```

EDIT: This only happends when i have only 1 row in my database? But when i have 2 it crashes?

Comment: 1-abc+1 ist not much different from abc. :) However, that is not your problem. Where exactly is the error thrown and what is its message?

Comment: you assume you always get all data once.. you get n chunks of data.. you have to account for that and you dont. this code may fail in some network environments

Comment: Is there any error thrown when it crashes? Are you able to debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
randomid = (int)1 + arc4random() % (1-responseRandomID+1);
```

can lead to / by 0 if responseRandomId == 2

if hardcoded e.g. 2 % 0 - the compiler catches it

if given via variable (as in your case) :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_DIV (divide by zero)
```